# Use Negation of Parameter in Symfony Config

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to use the Negation of a Parameter in symfony2/3 config files (e.g: app/config.yml)? for example:

```
parameters:
    a_true_parameter: true

some_config_key: # e.g: 'doctrine', or 'framework'
    some_key: !%a_true_parameter% # must evaluate to false
```

Comment: Doesn't work, get the message: `Expected boolean but got string`.

Comment: The comment above was a reply to a comment suggesting to use `"@=!parameter('parameter_name')"`